# Howl doesn't start immediately after onend

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I am making a video game with pure `HTML5` and `JavaScript`, and there is an error I am having where it waits 0 to 5 seconds after `onend` for the other song to play. I am trying to add a loop in the middle of the song that repeats forever until a certain thing happens. I already have most of that done apart from the delay. Here is my code. (Simplified)

```
function playMusic(source) {
    if(soundOn) {
        music = new Howl({
            src: [source],
            autoplay: true,
            loop: true,
            volume: (musicVol / 100),
            onend: function() {
                songEnded = 1;
                setTimeout(function() {songEnded = 0;}, 1000)
            }
        });
    }
}
function quickMusic() {
    if(soundOn) {
        music = new Howl({
            src: ['song_start.wav'],
            autoplay: true,
            loop: false,
            volume: (musicVol / 100),
            onend: function() {
                console.log("Finished!") //For debugging
                playMusic('song_loop.wav')
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, sorry for answering to my own question, but here is how I did it.

```
function quickMusic() {
    if(soundOn) {
        music1 = new Howl({
            src: ['song_loop.wav'],
            autoplay: false,
            loop: true,
            volume: (musicVol / 100),
            onend: function() {
                console.log("Finished!") //For debugging
            }
        });
        music = new Howl({
            src: ['song_start.wav'],
            autoplay: true,
            loop: false,
            volume: (musicVol / 100),
            onend: function() {
                console.log("Finished!") //For debugging
                TEMP = music1
                music1 = music
                music = TEMP //I had to add this because of a volume slider
                music.play()
            }
        });
    }
}
```